# Mysqli SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table returning false

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a strange problem with my msqli code. I copied a part of my other code and I got this:

```
$query=mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT COUNT (*) AS number FROM table");
$query=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$query=$query['number'];
```

I tought that i mistaken something but i found no problem in this code so i copy-pasted the whole other working code and it did not work, while it still worked perfectly in the other file. The query returns a boolean. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: put an alias on count, `COUNT(*) AS total`, then access the index as `echo $query['total']`, a simple `var_dump($query)` should have given you the hint

Comment: He did it with `COUNT (*) AS number`

Comment: @Ghost his COUNT has an alias

Comment: This could be the space between `COUNT` and `(*)`

Comment: plus the typo on the space remove it `COUNT ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting as a community wiki.*

From the MySQL manual on functions:

> *"By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function arguments are permitted."*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html

A: Remove the space from `COUNT (*)` => `COUNT(*)`.

- `COUNT()` is an aggregate "function".

And just for argument's sake; `table` is a MySQL reserved word, should that be its actual name.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

If you wish to still use that name (should it be the case), wrap it in ticks:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM `table`
```

Check for errors on the query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Plus, using the same `$query` variable, is bad practice.

Also make sure you're using the same MySQL API to connect with, being `mysqli_` and not a different one.

Comment: You were right with the whitespace characters. Originally i did not use the same variable and the table name but i wanted to make it easy to understand. Thank you for your help but i still don't know how it can work in the other file. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: @Gergerossza You're welcome. Work in which other file?

Comment: In any other php file but now i found the source of the problem. I had to make a video and the classmates who gave me the pictures for it infected my PC with an ****load of viruses. Now i hope i'm clear again. Most of the strange changes disappeared.